# Header file not found (cocos2d)

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, cocos2d-iphone

So I feel like this should be a simple problem, but I can't get the

```
'kazmath/...h' file  not found
```

error to disappear (specifically `kazmath.h` and `mat4.h`. This might be an extension (or revisit) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543659/header-files-in-cocos2d-not-found-box2d).

Here's an overview. I have a workspace for games and adding them individually as sibling projects. The one I just added uses Cocos2d. It seems to compile by itself, but when I try to link it to the workspace, the workspace gets errors that it can't find the `kazmath` folder. It is in the game project itself, and I have tried adding it to the workspace, but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone give a quick rundown on either adding projects to a workspace and linking them in or on how to properly link header files?

---

Some notes: I've added the path (Arcade/libs/kazmath/include/) in *Header Search Paths* for the build settings. I've added the `-lz` and `-ObjC` flags for the *Other Linker Flags*.

Comment: delete all files of cocos2d bundle and add again error will be solved.

Comment: wrong search path i think, check how the kazmath headers are included, if it's "kazmath/.../something.h" you have to remove that part of the path from the header search path. Also you should add it to user header search path if the includes are ot using <> anlge brackets.

Comment: Adding it to the user header search path did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you attempt to set Project Wide Header Search Paths section 
and you forgot a wrong section in 
in Target that maybe wrong overridden may cause keep this error occuring.

so delete targets>BLAHPROJ>Header Search Paths setting and keep this setting in ONLY Project Wide.
this fixes problem too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same problem as I have, which I am answering here because I have not found anyone giving this answer and maybe it will solve this issue for others.

I kept "fixing" the path in my Project target but, using a demo project as a template which builds a separate Cocos2D target, I should have been changing the "Header Search Paths" there.

--forehead slap!--

I am a bear of very little brain.